# How to import Ionicons (or other fonts) into a Vue-loader app?

Tags: webpack, vue-loader, ionicons

After installing `ionicons` v3.0.0 with npm, I am having a lot of trouble importing the fonts into my app:

```
// /src/App.vue
@import '../node_modules/ionicons/dist/scss/ionicons.scss';
```

seems to point to the right path, however, I get a ton of errors such as

```
Cannot find module "../fonts/ionicons.eot?v=3.0.0-alpha.3
```

Obviously, this problem stems from the font files, because for example, the file above is actually `ionicons.eot`, and not `ionicons.eot?v=3.0.0-alpha.3`.

I also found a [3-year old discussion on Github](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/css-loader/issues/18) and tried every single loader suggested in comments, but none of them worked. I am a newbie in Vue and webpack, so I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

**Question**: What do I need to do in order to be able to use Ionicons (or Font Awesome or any other font library really) in my app with vue-loader?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out myself. You just need to add an appropriate loader for the fonts

```
{ test: /\.(eot|woff|woff2|svg|ttf)([\?]?.*)$/, loader: "file-loader" }
```

to your `webpack` file. However, I also had to change the `@import` statement from `scss` to compiled `css`; otherwise, it wouldn't work (not sure why). Problem solved